Let $f,f'$ and $f''$ be entire functions such that each one is never equal to $0$. Show that $f= c \cdot e^{az}$ for some $c, a \in \mathbb{C}$
I have been stuck on this problem my professor gave me for quite some time. He couldn't solve it either and has heard it from a collegue. Taking for instance $e^{sin(z)}$ works for $f'$ but not $f''$ that has roots. Ideally, I would like to show that the following derivatives satisfy the same property or find some properties about $\frac{f'}{f}$ to show its constant, maybe by Liouville theorem but I don't see how. There might be a counterexample.

@RyszardSzwarc. The title has been updated.

Also I thought about Piccard theorem which states that the functions are surjective on $\mathbb{C*}$

This is called Saxer Theorem (see Nine Introductions to Complex Analysis by S Seagal note 3.11 on p 147 and the proof is quite non-trivial (requiring some deep though standard Nevanlinna Theory) and depends on the fact (a consequence of a Theorem of Milloux) that if $F$ is entire (nonconstant) either it is surjective or its derivative $F'$ cannot miss a value except zero.
The proof then follows considering $g =f/f'$ which is entire and noting that by hypothesis that if $g$ is nonconstant then it clearly misses $0$ (since $f$ does).
But $g'=1-ff''/f'^2$ misses $1$ since $ff''$ misses $0$ and that is a contradiction to the result quoted above.
Hence $g$ is constant and then $f=ce^{az}$
Note that the result quoted above essentially follows from the fact that if $H$ is entire non constant then $e^H$ is bigger in some sense than $H$ or any derivative of $H$ though of course when $H$ is not of finite order this requires Nevanlinna theory to quantify. Then $H'e^H-a$ must have roots for any $a\ne 0$ since otherwise you would get $H'e^H-e^W=a$ and then $H,W$ are "similar" and the above cannot hold for $a\ne 0$ - again this requires Nevanlinna theory when $H$ is not of finite order.
Note however that this result has been superseded by a Theorem of Gunther Frank (see same book page $148$ as above for reference) which shows that if $f$ and $f^{(k)}$ do not vanish for a given $k \ge 2$ then $f$ is as above. In particular only the hypothesis $f, f''$ do not vanish are enough to conclude that $f=ce^{az}$

It seems that it started with the doctoral thesis of Walter Saxer, which is available here: https://www.research-collection.ethz.ch/handle/20.500.11850/135460

@Martin - a complete proof of a slight extension (allowing for finitely many zeroes and meromorphic functions) is proven in Hayman treatise on meromorphic functions where this result is called Saxer theorem - the Seagal book is more elementary and probably more current and it has lots of discussions of this and similar topics - the idea is clear as I noted in the post ($e^H$ is "bigger" than $H$ or its derivatives but one needs Nevanlinna theory to quantify it)
